# How long does one revolution take for a rotating cd

Tags: physics

I have the question "When a cd rotates at an angular speed of 10.5 rads^-1, how long does one revolution take ?"

Here is my attempt.

[image]

Is this correct ?

Comment: except for the numerical accuracy, it is correct.

Comment: ROughly speaking, it is perfect.  Of course $2\pi/10.5$ is not precisely 0.6, but you have the right idea.

Comment: So what would be a more accurate answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.59839860068 would be the result of the division, but it needs to be rounded to the least numerical accuracy of measurement values. 2 and $\pi$ are not measurement values, but 10.5 is.

10.5 has 3 ["Significant figures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

So your answer also has to have 3 significant figures. The leading 0. do not count, so 0.598 would be the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you (: I understand now.